# Create Public Key using OpenSSL instead of PuTTYgen for PKCS#8

Tags: encryption, openssl, key-generation, authorization, openssh

I'm trying to create a public key pair for ssh-rsa authentication.  If I'm using puttygen.exe, the "OpenSSH authorized_keys file" string looks like this:

> "ssh-rsa AAAAB3 ... 6yIK9Nbw== rsa-key-20150709"

This works fine, however I would like to attempt to create such a file using OpenSSL instead. Mostly because I just want to convert/create a private key later in PKCS#8 format using:

> openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 des3

I read this can be done independent of the public key after the fact.  So I used "openssl" and just generated a key, but I couldn't get it into the "ssh-rsa" format .

Does anybody know how to "convert" or output my public key to the seemingly standard "OpenSSH authorized_keys file" without using PuTTY tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenSSH format is unsurprisingly supported by **OpenSSH tools**. (The OpenSSH public-key format, used in `authorized_keys` and with a prefix added in `known_hosts`, isn't itself a "de jure" standard, but is a trivial modification of a public-key encoding within the SSH2 *protocol* which is standardized.)

Less obviously, OpenSSH uses OpenSSL format(s) for *private* keys, although they recently (6.5) added a optional format of their own. Thus a private-key file you generated with OpenSSL *is* an OpenSSH private key, and OpenSSH can convert it to an OpenSSH *public* key with the **`-y` option of `ssh-keygen`**. See http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1?query=ssh-keygen .

(Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271197/openssl-how-to-extract-public-key 
and https://serverfault.com/questions/52285/create-a-public-ssh-key-from-the-private-key .)

Comment: Hah, I did read about I did read about doing it using ssh-keygen, but is there a way to do this on a Windows machine?  Nevermind, found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771378/ssh-keygen-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command